# Prove exists embedding $\phi: \mathbb {Z}_3 \times \mathbb {Z}_3 \times \mathbb {Z}_3 \to S_{27}$ s.t. ${\rm Im}\phi$ intersects 2 conjugacy classes.

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism, permutation-cycles

**Question:**

Prove exists an embedding $\phi: \mathbb {Z}_3 \times \mathbb {Z}_3 \times \mathbb {Z}_3 \to S_{27}$ such that ${\rm Im}\phi$ intersects exactly 2 conjugacy classes of $S_{27}$.

---

**I'm pretty stuck on formalizing and continuing my proof. I will share what I've done so far, and maybe someone can help me out:**

So first of all let us mark $G =  \mathbb {Z}_3 \times  \mathbb {Z}_3 \times  \mathbb {Z}_3$.

Secondly from combinatorial reasons we have $|G| = 3^3 = 27$.

Let us examine the action of $G \mapsto G$ on itself by multiplication from the left.

Let us examine the induced homomorphism $\phi:G \to S_{27}$.

Let $g \in G$. If $g \in$ Ker$\phi$ then we have $\phi(g) = Id_{27}$ and $\phi(g)$ is in the conjugacy class of ().

Otherwise, assume $g \notin$ Ker$\phi$. Let us mark $\phi(g) = \psi_g$ such that:

$\psi_g:G \to G$ upholds for some $\;g^{'} \in G\;$, $\psi(g^{'}) = gg^{'}$.

If we mark $g = \langle a,b,c \rangle$ for some $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_3$ then notice:

$|\langle a,b,c \rangle| \in \{1,2,3\}$ since $(0+0+0),(1+1+1),(2+2+2) \equiv 0 \;(mod 3)$.

**So I'm having a hard time continuing from here unfortunately and would love some help...**

Comment: What do you know about the conjugacy classes of $S_{27}$? That is an essential piece of backgound knowledge here. Without it you cannot proceed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes of course it’s crucial. I know 2 cycles are conjugated if the have the same cycle structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, learn about the conjugacy classes in symmetric groups. Any conjugacy class is the set of all permutations with a given cycle type. There are many resources explaining this.

Then, you must show $\phi(g)$ is a product of $3$-cycles for any nontrivial $g$.

Note $g^3=e$ but $g\ne e$. This automatically implies $\phi(g)^3=e$. Thus, every cycle of $\phi(g)$ has length $1$ or $3$, and we can rule out length $1$. (Why?)

The fact that $G=\mathbb{Z}_3^3$ is actually not relevant. In the regular representation of *any* group, $\phi(g)$ is a product of equal-length cycles. So you don't need to use anything about $\mathbb{Z}_3^3$ other than the fact that it is a finite group.

Comment: I might’ve miss mentioned this in my question but i know 2 cycles are conjugated in $S_n$ if they have the same cycle structure. I’m not sure i follow your comment regarding the fact G itself is not relevant. Perhaps you can elaborate.

Comment: @AsiMathStudent By "2 cycles are conjugated" you mean "two permutations are conjugate." The term *cycle* refers to a specific type of permutation, and we're talking about permutations in general not just cycles. And even if you want to refer to two cycles, don't say "2 cycles" because that can be confused with "2-cycles" which are a particular kind of cycle. | Like I said, the proof $\phi(g)$ is a product of equal-length cycles (at least the proof you want to shoot for) should apply for any group $G$, not just $\Bbb Z_3^3$. Have you tried proving all cycles of $\phi(g)$ are equal length yet?

Comment: First of all you are very much correct and I apologize for using the wrong term. Secondly I did try showing all cycles of $\phi(g)$ are equal length but I am stuck on that part.

Comment: Consider the cycle containing an arbitrary $x$. It goes $(x~gx~\cdots g^{k-1}x)$, where $g^{k-1}$ is the largest power of $g$ before $g^kx=x$. But that last equation is equivalent to $g^k=e$. So $k$, the length of the cycle containing the arbitrary element $x$, is the order of $g$, regardless of what $x$ is. That is, $\phi(g)$ will always be a product of length-$k$ cycles, where $k$ is the order of $g\in G$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider three $3$-cycles $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3$ in $S_{27}$ with disjoint supports, so they commute. Then the map $f: (k_1+3\mathbb{Z},k_2+3\mathbb{Z},k_3+3\mathbb{Z}) \mapsto \gamma_1^{k_1}\gamma_2^{k_2}\gamma_3^{k_3}$ from $(\mathbb{Z}/3)^3$ to $S_{27}$ is well-defined and is an injective group homomorphism. Its image contains elements of four different conjugation classes, namely products of $r$ disjoint $3$-cycles, for $0 \le r \le 3$.